# wpf Открыть форму внутри panel etc c#

Tags: c#, wpf, form

Нужно по нажатию кнопки отобразить форму на панели (stackpanel) или другом компоненте (TabControl etc). Для winforms не сложно:

```
Form2 frm = new Form2();
frm.TopLevel = false;
frm.Visible = true;
frm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
frm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
this.Panel1.Focus();
this.Panel1.Controls.Add(frm);
```

Но как это сделать в wpf ? Пытался так :

```
Form2 frm = new Form2();
panel_info.Children.Add(frm); //stackpanel
```

и так

```
Form2 frm = new Form2();
tb.Children.Add(frm); //TabControl
```

Получаю ошибку `Объект Window должен быть корнем дерева. Нельзя добавить объект Window как дочерний объект для Visual.`

немного погуглив наткнулся на ссылку http://www.codescratcher.com/wpf/mdi-parent-window-in-wpf/ , но т.к там нужно подключать стороннюю либу, то мне не подходит. Есть ли способ это реализовать стандартными способами ? не прибегаю к сторонним либам и тп

Comment: совсем не понятно что нужно получить, можно скриншот добавить?

Comment: Form2 используется где-нибудь как отдельное окно или только как вложенное?

Comment: @FoggyFinder мне нужно что-то наподобие этого https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Smc7-5lYcE , только для wpf. Тобишь, я в treeview  выделяю определенную строку и в зависимости от того, что я выделил появляется та или иная инфа, прст инфы много и с формой мне показалось удобнее

Comment: Вам нужен просто привязать `SelectedItem` из `ListView` к `ContentPresenter`

Comment: @АртемНиколаевич я его создавал только с этой целью, нигде отдельно не использую. Что бы было более понятно, то посмотрите видео, что я отправил выше

Comment: @FoggyFinder перепутал, не `listview`, а `treeview` . У вас не найдется примера ?

Comment: `treeView` или `listView` не имеет существенной разницы

Comment: Примера нет, но написать его совсем не сложно.

Comment: @FoggyFinder если вас не затруднит, то не могли ли бы вы привести пример ? мне это бы помогло, спасибо

Comment: sure, вот пример - http://megadarja.blogspot.com/2010/04/mvvm-wpf.html

Comment: @FoggyFinder спасибо, гляну

Comment: но мне кажется вы не с того начинаете, оставил свой совет [в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40762963#40762963)